# After I added Chromium Embedded Framework, code signing is failing

Tags: macos, chromium-embedded

I create a plain Cocoa Objective-C project to experiment with CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework). I copied the file "Chromium Embedded Framework.framework" to my project, added it as an embedded binary, like this:

[image]

Since then, my compilation fails at code signing time with this error:

```
CodeSign /Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cefobjc-bxtruyemnyagwwgdejtzuxngovsr/Build/Products/Debug/cefobjc.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium\ Embedded\ Framework.framework/Versions/A
    cd /Users/pupeno/Projects/macninja-demos/cefobjc
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "-"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules /Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cefobjc-bxtruyemnyagwwgdejtzuxngovsr/Build/Products/Debug/cefobjc.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium\ Embedded\ Framework.framework/Versions/A

Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
/Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cefobjc-bxtruyemnyagwwgdejtzuxngovsr/Build/Products/Debug/cefobjc.app/Contents/Frameworks/Chromium Embedded Framework.framework/Versions/A: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A framework is a hierarchical directory with different versions in Cocoa,you must create a major version for the framework to ensure your framework can be signed correctly.
As we know , the CEF framework has a structure which is incompatible with the sign mechanism and different from the expected structure.So we need to modify it, like this:[A hierarchical directory of cocoa framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rd9S.jpg)

Furthermore,you need to sign the lib or plugs contained in the framework respectively, we maybe code like this...

codesign -s "${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" -f "${PLUGIN_PATH}"